# Graph Api to add external users to a group chat

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

is there a way to add an external member to the group [not the guest user who is part of the ADD]
the graph api seems to accept only the ADDconversation member ,
is it possible to add an external user ?

Comment: You need to invite them first, you can do so via the Azure AD (preview) module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-invite-powershell
Or the corresponding Graph API endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

You need to invite them first, you can do so via the **Azure AD (preview) module:**

To send an invitation to your test email account, run the following PowerShell command (replace "John Doe" and john@contoso.com with your test email account name and email address):

```
New-MgInvitation -InvitedUserDisplayName "John Doe" -InvitedUserEmailAddress John@contoso.com -InviteRedirectUrl "https://myapplications.microsoft.com" -SendInvitationMessage:$true
```

The command sends an invitation to the email address specified.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-invite-powershell

Or the corresponding **Graph API endpoint:**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "admin@fabrikam.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.contoso.com"
}
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http